# PHP/codeigniter barcode and qr code generator in single library

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, qr-code, barcode

Is there any library/class/plugin available for generating QR code and Barcode?
I am getting is two different libraries for each one of them.
It will be good if I can get in single library with both functionality.

After google I found few links like this:

https://github.com/dwisetiyadi/CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code
https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-qr-codes-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Codeigniter library for QR Code generation with various options like business card , phone numbers etc...
https://github.com/naseemfasal/InfiQr-codeigniter/

For barcode you can try this:-
https://github.com/desta88/Codeigniter-Barcode-Generator-Zend-Library/tree/master/application

But i am not sure about the availability of a library which do both.